# Looking for algorithm to map an image to 4 sides polygon

Tags: algorithm, delphi, graphics

This is more a math question than a programming question beside the fact that I must implement it using Delphi inside a graphic application.

Assuming I have a picture of a sheet of paper. The actual sheet of paper is of course a rectangular area. When the picture is shown on a computer screen the rectangular area is no more rectangular because when the picture was taken, the camera was not perfectly positioned above the sheet of paper. There is all kinds of perspective effects which result in deformations.

My application needs to tweak the image so that the original rectangular area is displayed as a rectangular area on screen.

Most photo processing software have an interactive tool to do that. The user draw a rectangular area on screen around the rectangular object and then drag each corner to deform the displayed rectangular area until he see the real area as rectangular. What I'm looking for is the algorithm to do that computation.

Comment: This is way too broad, and there is no "algorithm" for doing this - you can design a *process* to do this, involving many steps with algorithms for each step.  Which part are you stuck on?  Try to break this down - do you know how to do edge detection?  That seems like a sensible first step.  Once you have edges you can start translating that into lines in a coordinate space.  Do you need help doing that?  Then linear transformation to a new coordinate space.  Do you need help doing that?  If the answer is yes to all of it then you need to slow down and take this one step at a time...

Comment: It is not as complex as it sounds. I can solve it but before reinventing the wheel, I ask... The problem is close to a bilinear interpolation.

Comment: look at graphics32 there are some functions to solve these

Comment: @fpiette If you're asking how to solve this entire problem it is too broad for Stack Overflow and therefore off topic.  If you're asking for a library to do this, then this is also off-topic.

Comment: The opposite of this is texture mapping - going from a rectangular image to a polygon onscreen. You may find googling techniques for that useful, since you need to do the inverse.

Comment: You could also probably build a simple technique by building a map between the polygon onscreen and the desired rectangle, if you know which corner points correspond to which. You can then go for any coordinate X 0-1 (move along the top and bottom lines, say, 0.5 of their length each; any Y coordinate will fall on the line between those two points) and then any coordinate Y 0-1 (somewhere along the line you just drew.) Do a lookup. This will be slow; you can then modify it to use a scanline sort of algorithm, moving at a specific resolution over the polygon.

Comment: I wrote a library that can warp images:
https://github.com/mikerabat/mrimgutil
https://github.com/mikerabat/mrmath

(you need both)... You find there functions to either warp one triangulation to another one. In addition you can also use thin plate splines which would create a little smoother result. You can check the libraries unit testing application to see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the problem into 2 steps. Find the edges or corners of the sheet and remap the pixels.

To find the corners or edges it's a really hard problem since they might be invisible, outside of the picture, obstructed, bent or deformed. Assuming you have a very simple setup (black uniform background, white paper, very little distortion) you could run an [edge detection kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection) over the image then find the 4 outer edges. If you find the edges you can intersect them to find the corners and the other way around.

Once you find the corners run an interpolation over the image to map the pixels onto the rectangle you want. You should be able to get the graphics engine to do this for you if you provide the coordinates of the corners as texture coordinates for the rectangle and map the image as a texture.

I made it sound simple, but you will encounter many parameters to set and experiment with.

Answer (score 1):

It seems *(because you mentioned bilinear interpolation)* that you need perspective transformations.

There is implementation of perspective transformations (mapping of arbitrary convex quad to rectangle and vice versa) in Anti-Grain Geometry library ([exe example](http://www.antigrain.com/perspective.zip)). [Delphi port](http://www.crossgl.com/aggpas/).

With `agg_trans_perspective` one can calculate the matrix of persp. transformation and then apply it to map coordinates from one quad to another.